# getEditors() getOwners()

Tags: google-apps-script

can i get editors & authors of all the pages of site separately from Apps Script.
I want to do it because I am using Page Level Permissions for pages. So seperate pages have seperate **owners & editors**.

```
var site = SitesApp.getActiveSite();
var pages = site.getChildren();
Logger.log(pages[0].getAuthors());
//Logger.log(pages[0].getEditors());  there is no getEditors() method for page instead of site.
```

In Log it is displaying only creator of the page for any page.

I am not able to get those in Apps Script... any idea???

Answer (score 0):

the method `.getEditors()` applies to site, not to pages. You can only define permission on a site level, just as in the sites settings you set manually in the 'manage site' tab.

You mention that you are *'using Page Level Permissions for pages'*, how did you do that ?